# LESS - Convert negative value to a positive

Tags: less

I'm trying to convert a negative variable in lesscss in to a positive:

```
@var: -100px;

.test {
  height: @var * -1; // expect result to be 100px
}
```

But when I try and compile this code, I get 'unrecognized input' error.

Comment: *I get 'unrecognized input' error.* - it [should be fine](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40var%3A%20-100px%3B%5Cn%5Cn.test%20%7B%5Cn%20%20height%3A%20%40var%20*%20-1%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D). So make sure the error message you get actually points to that statement and not something else.

Comment: Btw., just `-@var` would be fine too (though mul by `-1` is usually safer for more complex expressions because of ambiguous `-` meaning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Abs function:

```
@var: -100px;

.test {
  height: abs(@var);
}
```